# Animated Can't Scroll Up the content

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm getting stuck at scroll the content with Animated. When I click on the arrow button, only the Animated tag scrolls up but the content inside it.

Here is my detail image:
[image]

And when I click the button:
[image]

And here is my code: 
 This is my function:
[image]

This is render:
[image]

And this is my style:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're animating the view's height rather than scroll position.

Instead, try animating the y offset of [`scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true})`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollto)

more info here...
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollto
 `